# Is it possible to compile and test a single module in Rust? (Ignoring build errors in the rest of the project)

Tags: rust

Is there any way to forcefully compile a *single module* and run its tests in Rust, even though the rest of the project doesn't compile? (Assuming the target module and all of its dependencies compile successfully)

---

### Rationale

I'm having a recurring challenge in Rust. Whenever I need to refactor anything, I have to completely finish the refactor across my entire codebase before I can run any tests. This issue gets exponentially worse the lower level the refactored module is.

For example, let's say I need to slightly change the shape of the central `Node` struct in a parser library. As soon as I do this, 100 build errors pop up in 12 different files around my repository.

This is excellent, because it gives me a concrete list of issues I now have to fix, after which my application very probably works just as I intended from the beginning.

However, what if it takes me 2 hours to finish the refactor so my build succeeds, then as soon as I run my tests it immediately becomes obvious that I overlooked something and the refactor can't work. If I was allowed to build the core module that contains `Node` and run the tests right away, I might have saved several hours of effort.

Comment: Only if you can extract that module into a separate crate that can exist on its own.

Comment: @PitaJ I can do that. The build errors are all in modules that depend on the current module, but the current module and all its dependencies compile just fine. I could extract the current module and all its dependencies into a new crate and run the tests there, but that's also a lot of effort (though probably less.)

Comment: @PitaJ What would be perfect was if `cargo test -- mypackage::some_module` only compiled the target module and its dependencies. Instead, Cargo still tries to compile the entire crate, most of which is not actually needed for running the target tests.

Comment: One thing you might try is adding an example or integration test that pulls in the given module with `#[path = "../src/foo.rs"] mod foo;`